Conversational Rag Chain with tools
i'm following this example text
with this code:
import bs4
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Text, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever, create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_chroma import Chroma
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import ChatMessageHistory
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)

# Define the SQLite database
DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///chat_history.db"
Base = declarative_base()

.
.
.

rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain)

### Statefully manage chat history ###
store = {}

conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    rag_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="input",
    history_messages_key="chat_history",
    output_messages_key="answer",
)

# Invoke the chain and save the messages after invocation
def invoke_and_save(session_id, input_text):
    # Save the user question with role "human"
    save_message(session_id, "human", input_text)
    
    result = conversational_rag_chain.invoke(
        {"input": input_text},
        config={"configurable": {"session_id": session_id}}
    )["answer"]

    # Save the AI answer with role "ai"
    save_message(session_id, "ai", result)
    return result```

after add this function
@tool
def call_this():
    """"call this function"""
    return "function called"

and add bindtools here:
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0).bind_tools(tools=call_this)
When tools called the answer return empty.
Checking logs, tool is called, this is the reason the answer is empty.
My question is:
How i can continue using the code, but catching when tool is called?
